# Getting a specific value from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to get a specific column from an array for each record returned.

The array is called fields and one of the arrays in the array is locations. I'm looking for a specific column in the array called name.

Here's what I have:

```
foreach ($new_results as $result):?>
$locations = array_map($result->locations->location,function($obj) {   return $obj->location; });
echo implode(",",$locations);
endforeach;
```

I'm connecting to a web service to pull this data. The above is the code that the company gave me, but they haven't tested it as far as I know. It doesn't work for me.

Here's the call to the API

```
$results = $connection->call('groups/getAll', $params=array("suspended" => "no","fields" =>"locations"));
$new_results = $results->groups->group;
```

Here's an example from the API.

```
{
"id": "xxxx",
"fields": {
    "locations": [
        "North",
        "Central"
    ]
}
}
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong? I'm still very new to PHP so I may be missing something very obvious.

Comment: please format code properly

Comment: That example looks like JSON to me and it contains an object, not an inner array.

Answer (score 0):

How to get json using curl:
[How to get JSON data from Rest API by PHP Curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32179301/how-to-get-json-data-from-rest-api-by-php-curl)

Now with that in mind you can dive a little deeper into the object manipulation in terms of the response here: [Accessing JSON object elements in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285314/accessing-json-object-elements-in-php).

```
//""" code from the first link 

$service_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/thesis/?format=json";
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
//execute the session
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
//finish off the session
curl_close($curl);
$curl_jason = json_decode($curl_response, true);
print_r($curl_jason);

//""" code from the first link
```

&

```
//""" code from the second link

/*Variable passed in from the ExtJS interface as JSON object*/
$json = $_POST["newUserInfo"];
//$json = '{"USER":{"ID":"","FULL_USER_NAME":"Some Guy","ENTERPRISE_USER_NAME":"guyso01","USER_EMAIL":"Some.Guy@Email.com","USER_PHONE":"123-456-7890"},"PERMISSIONS":{"ID":"","USER_ID":"","IS_ADMIN":"true"},"SETTINGS":{"ID":"","USERS_ID":"","BACKGROUND":"default"}}';

//Test to view the decoded output
//var_dump(json_decode($json));

//Decode the $json variable
$jsonDecoded = json_decode($json,true);

//Create arrays for each table from the $jsonDecoded object
$user_info = array($jsonDecoded['USER']);
$permissions_info = array($jsonDecoded['PERMISSIONS']);
$settings_info = array($jsonDecoded['SETTINGS']); 

// """ code from the first link
```